# xpath to select a pattern with any number + "specific string"

Tags: string, xpath, text, numbers

xpath for such span with text containing a number and a string

```
<span>10 days</span>
```

I have tried this one - `//span[contains(text(), 'days') and matches(text(), '\d+ days')]` but its not working

Comment: Which XPath processor, which XPath version do you use? How exactly does your attempt fail. For instance, with XPath 3.1 at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/ the `span` element is selected by your expression.

Comment: the `matches` function doesn't exist in XPath 1.0; also, for newer versions of XPath, you can get rid of the `contains` condition, just `//span[matches(text(), "^\d+ days$")]` is enough

Comment: Don't tell us it isn't working, tell us how it fails (symptoms are everything when diagnosing problems). There's a world of difference between failing to find the matches() function (which would mean you're probably using XPath 1.0), and not getting a match (which might mean you ignored namespaces in the input document).

Comment: If the `contains` attempt is finding nothing, I would suspect a namespace issue.

Comment: @MartinHonnen HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @MartinHonnen $x("")

Comment: `$x` uses the browser's support for XPath and that is restricted to XPath 1.0 which doesn't have any support for a `matches` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 1.0 doesn't support regexps. Fortunately, `^\d+ days$` is simple enough for you to write an equivalent condition with the limited set of string functions that XPath 1.0 provides:

```
//span[
    substring-after(text()," ") = "days" and
    substring-before(text()," ") != "" and
    translate(substring-before(text()," "), "0123456789", "") = ""
]
```

---

###### example

input:

```xml
<div>
    <!-- matching examples -->
    <span>10 days</span>
    <span>365 days</span>
    <span>2 days</span>

    <!-- non-matching examples -->
    <span> days</span>
    <span>100 </span>
    <span>X days</span>
    <span>10 months</span>
    <span> 3 days</span>
    <span>4 days </span>
    <span>5  days</span>
    <span>6days</span>
</div>
```

result:

```
10 days
365 days
2 days
```